# getting zero values for lat and long values of top right corner of map in android maps version2

Tags: android

> how to get map right top corner lat and long values for map in andorid
>   maps api v2 when activiy created. I wrote the code but some how
>   getting zeros.

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        implements OnClickListener {

  private GoogleMap mapView;

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(34.59,
                -113.236), 7));

    //** getting null values on the following line **
    LatLng values = mapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

Comment: `moveCamera()` probably does not take immediate effect. Try checking later to see what your visible region is.

Comment: no body is there to help me, atleast tell what is the procedure i am new to android

Comment: visible region is getting zeros.